# Permutations of array with language codes

Tags: php, algorithm, permutation

I have array

```
$langs = array('en', 'de', 'pt', .....);
```

and now I would like to generate an array like this:

```
$result = array(
  array('en' => array('de', 'pt'),
  array('de' => array('en', 'pt'),
  array('pt' => array('en', 'de'),
  ....
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the result with [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$langs = array("en", "de", "pt");        

foreach($langs as $val) 
{
        $array[$val] = array_values(array_diff($langs, array($val)));      
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
 $langs = array('en', 'de', 'pt');
 $arr = array();
 foreach($langs as $key => $lang){
        $arr[$lang] = $langs;
        unset($arr[$lang][$key]);
        sort($arr[$lang]);
 }

 print_r($arr);
```

CHECK **[PHP FIDDLE](http://3v4l.org/91PVl)**